# Chrome не отображает svg картинку через <img>

Tags: html, css, svg, google-chrome

`Chrome` не отображает `svg` картинку добавленную в `HTML` с помощью `<img>`, в остальных браузерах все хорошо.

Подключаю так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтобы понять причины и помочь вам в решении, необходим код вашего svg файла. Нужен код, а не скриншот.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример использования тега `<img>` для добавления `SVG` файла в `HTML` страничку.

```
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"/>`
```

Другие способы добавления `svg` в `HTML` - [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

*Ниже код странички, вызов svg картинки выполнен дважды,- с разными размерами*

```html
<style>
.pic1 {
float:left;
}

img {
margin:0.5em;
} 
p {
float:left;
}
</style>
<div class="pic1">
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"/>
</div>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec vehicula est non nunc ultricies, sit amet pharetra nulla congue. Vestibulum hendrerit ante ac rhoncus aliquet. Quisque vitae est turpis. Nulla sit amet felis nec nisl blandit mollis.
Nullam ornare turpis quis orci hendrerit, vitae varius est tincidunt. In quis malesuada tellus. Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. Integer congue facilisis enim porta pretium. Morbi scelerisque tincidunt purus, vitae rhoncus tortor tristique nec. Nullam laoreet turpis nec felis vehicula finibus.
</p> 
<div class="pic1">
<img width="100" height="100" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"/>
</div>

<p>
Nullam ornare turpis quis orci hendrerit, vitae varius est tincidunt. In quis malesuada tellus. Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. Integer congue facilisis enim porta pretium. Morbi scelerisque tincidunt purus, vitae rhoncus tortor tristique nec. Nullam laoreet turpis nec felis vehicula finibus.

Fusce ultricies maximus ante vitae imperdiet. Proin magna orci, pretium nec pretium id, ultricies in risus. Praesent mauris ipsum, semper nec convallis sit amet, vestibulum non enim. Quisque volutpat nulla ac nulla venenatis, ac cursus nulla laoreet. Aliquam malesuada dui a orci tristique tristique. Phasellus fringilla, velit eget ultrices efficitur, justo lacus elementum lorem, nec convallis augue lacus non dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris sagittis, sapien in tristique mollis, ex libero laoreet magna, ut pellentesque dolor augue accumsan elit. Nunc ut augue at eros sollicitudin malesuada. Pellentesque urna felis, posuere sit amet odio et, vestibulum aliquet ex. Nulla eu dolor blandit, bibendum nibh in, tincidunt ex. Ut nisl justo, tincidunt a augue et, gravida sollicitudin neque. Donec id dignissim elit, a sollicitudin leo. Aliquam placerat orci justo, et faucibus nibh volutpat vel.
</p>
Nulla varius, est eu dictum vulputate, risus tellus euismod augue, ac tempus velit elit nec dui. Duis eleifend metus eu nisi mattis scelerisque. Proin finibus neque ut pellentesque porta. Etiam quis ligula non ligula sollicitudin efficitur at a turpis. Morbi tristique maximus quam eu imperdiet. Morbi dolor augue, sagittis non urna quis, fringilla scelerisque erat. Praesent et tempor tortor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ut consectetur arcu, id vestibulum sapien. Integer in metus et lacus sollicitudin sollicitudin. Curabitur vulputate mollis odio, sit amet dictum mauris condimentum non. Vestibulum enim risus, luctus a tristique sit amet, semper non enim. Nunc laoreet hendrerit massa at blandit.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris dapibus eu ipsum ac semper. Suspendisse turpis nunc, mattis sit amet lorem id, fringilla iaculis purus. Praesent egestas est id ullamcorper tristique. Nulla tempus sem rutrum, sagittis dui quis, condimentum massa. Nam efficitur purus sed sapien euismod imperdiet. Donec laoreet augue eget justo dapibus suscipit. Etiam eleifend neque iaculis, pellentesque elit vel, malesuada justo. Aenean efficitur eros quis mattis convallis. Quisque hendrerit libero ligula, vel fermentum orci ultrices vel. In porttitor congue interdum. Duis ac vehicula est. Nullam sollicitudin eros a tortor semper, laoreet facilisis neque hendrerit. Integer faucibus elementum nibh, id venenatis urna consectetur a.
```

**Работает во всех современных браузерах и в IE11, Edge**